# Issue when merging a hotfix branch in Git: Unwanted commits during merge in dev

Tags: git

I'm facing an issue when trying to merge a **hotfix** branch in my Git project. The branch structure includes **dev**, **staging**, and **master**. The situation is as follows:

1. I created a **hotfix** branch from **master** to address a production issue.
2. I successfully merged the **hotfix** branch into **master**.
3. When attempting to merge **hotfix** into **dev** and **staging**, I noticed that additional commits are included in **dev** that weren't present before.

After investigating, I believe these additional commits stem from conflicts during the merge of **dev** into **staging**. However, I'm seeking a way to prevent these additional commits from being included in **dev**.

**Dynamic Configuration:**
I have a configuration file named **config.json**, which contains specific URLs that the code should point to depending on the branch. This configuration is utilized during code execution.

**Development Preferences:**
I want to avoid using **cherry-pick** to maintain better code traceability.

**Historical Merge Flow:**
Throughout the repository's history, the typical merge flow has been **dev** > **staging** > **master**.

**Steps Taken:**

1. Created the **hotfix** branch from **master**.
2. Made necessary changes and merged into **master**.
3. Attempted to merge into **dev** and **staging**, but unwanted commits were included in **dev**.

**Questions**:

1. What is the best practice for merging a **hotfix** branch into multiple branches, especially when conflicts arise?
2. How can I prevent additional conflict commits from being included in **dev** during the merge of the **hotfix** branch, particularly when conflicts arise in the **staging** merge?
3. Is there a recommended strategy for managing the **config.json** file to ensure that URLs are correct based on the branch after the merge, without resorting to **cherry-pick**?

**Additional Information:**

Branch structure: **master**, **dev**, and **staging**.
Issue branchs always created from **dev**

Any suggestions or guidance would be highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Avoid unwanted commits and preserve config.json.

Comment: "*Development Preferences: I want to avoid using cherry-pick to maintain better code traceability*" sounds like cargo cult. Cherry-picking is fine. Edit the cherry-picked commits' messages to add all the info you need if you want more traceability.